# Display in dropdown elements from SQL

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql

I want to display the strings from my variable allCompanies in a dropdown. I tried to list it with javascript like this, but it doesn't work:

```
function Requests(){
        var companiesList = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(allCompanies));
        for (var i = 0; i <= companiesList.length - 1; i++) {
            $('#Company').append('<option value="' + companiesList[i] + '">' + companiesList[i] + '</option>');
        }
    }
```

My html code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Select company to see requests: </p>
     <select id="Company" name="Company" class="form-control custom-select">
            <option value="">Select company.</option>
     </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it generate the wrong HTML, no HTML, or something else?

Comment: I doesn't populate the dropdown list. In console log I have the correct values. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or if I miss something.

Comment: What does the line with `var companiesList =` look like in the source of the page? It should be of the form `var companiesList = ["Acme", "Globex", "Stark"];`.

Comment: var companiesList looks like ['Acme', 'Globex', 'Stark'].

Comment: And every companiesList[i] display the correct value. But it doesn't display in the dropdown list.

Comment: 1) If you put the rendered page in a validator such as [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), does it pass? I'm wondering if there are accidentally two tags with the same id. 2) Are there any errors reported in the console?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in your HTML code, you are not actually calling the function you created at all under specific call `onKeyUp`, `onChange` etc.

Since you only want to fill the select options in order to initialize them (if I am getting this right), you could just initialize them after the HTML page has loaded.

So I would suggest you to simply use your code in the `$(document).ready(function()){}` as shown below :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var companiesList = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(allCompanies));
    for (var i = 0; i <= companiesList.length - 1; i++) {
        $('#Company').append('<option value="' + companiesList[i] + '">' + companiesList[i] + '</option>');
    }

});
```